# How to make footnote bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, biblatex

I want the citation in the footnote of the page it is being cited. How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe the [footbib package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/footbib.html) will be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the biblatex package as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}      
\bibliography{mem}            
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}     
\begin{document}
my text my text \autocite{ref}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty] % if you want a bibiography at the end as well
\end{document}
```

Have a look at the guide for other options/behaviors.