# Mark text as plain text

Tags: urls

When inserting a URL in a footnote

```
\footnote{http://www.bmu-klimaschutzinitiative.de/de/projekte_nki?p=1\&d=450, gesichtet am 21.10.2012}
```

there are two errors that missing `$` signs have been inserted. How can I mark the URL as plain text?

Comment: if you use the `url` package, that should help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dedicated [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package or the [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package will help you here.

### `url`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\footnote{\url{http://www.bmu-klimaschutzinitiative.de/de/projekte_nki?p=1&d=450}, gesichtet am 21.10.2012}
\end{document}
```

The font can be changed with `\urlstyle` ([`url` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/url) section 3 “Style”, works with `hyperref`, too):

- `\urlstyle{tt}`: mono-spaced typewriter font (default)
- `\urlstyle{rm}`: roman (serif) font
- `\urlstyle{sf}`: sans-serif font
- `\urlstyle{same}`: same font as the sourrounding text

### `hyperref`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\footnote{\url{http://www.bmu-klimaschutzinitiative.de/de/projekte_nki?p=1&d=450}, gesichtet am 21.10.2012}
\end{document}
```

The `hyperref` package defines a few other macros that handle URLs:

- `\href{<URL>}{<text>}`: “The `<text>` is made a hyperlink to the `<URL>`.” (not recommended in printed documents)
- `\nolinkurl{<URL>}`: similar to the output of the `url` package, no link will be created.

---

If you need to use more references in your footnotes, you also might be interested in more [automatic solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5606/16595).