# Turn footnotes into bibliography section

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes

I have written my document with 50 `\{footnote}` elements. I now realize I need to produce a bibliography page at the end of the doc.
Is there any way to have LaTeX turn those footnotes into a bibliography section?
Do I need to change them all to `\autocite{}` elements and then include something like this

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty] % if you want a bibiography at the end as well
\end{document}
```

[As per this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5606/how-to-make-footnote-bibliography)

Comment: That depends on how exactly your `\footnote`s look at the moment. If they contain the raw text of the citations, additional work will be needed to convert them to a `.bib` file to make them usable with `biblatex`. If you are already using a `.bib` file, things might be easier. It is also not quite clear to me what the expected output should be. Can you clarify that a bit? Ideally you would also include a short example document (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of how your `\footnote`s look now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert all your footnotes in endnotes and then call them "References":

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes,lipsum}
\let\footnote\endnote
\renewcommand{\notesname}{References}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]\footnote{\lipsum[4][1-3]}
\lipsum[7-14]\footnote{\lipsum[5][1-3]}
\lipsum[15-17]\footnote{\lipsum[6][1-3]}
{\parindent 0pt\parskip 2ex
\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\theendnotes}
\end{document}
```

But for a proper format, the best will be make a .bib file and manually replace the footnotes by citations commands and use bibtex or biblatex in a standard way.